# How can i fix this __trunc__ error?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, truncate

I'm using raspberry pi because i need a GUI to display my LED blinker counter project. I'm having an error in

```
IntVar()
```

It says that it has attribute error `__trunc__`  Here is my code:

```
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import math
from Tkinter import *

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("Simple Counter")

counter = IntVar()

def onClick1(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get()+1)

def onClick2(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get()-1)

def count():
    for x in range(0, counter):
        GPIO.output(16, True)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.output(16, False)

 entry = Entry(root, textvariable=counter).pack()
 button = Button(root, text="Press to Add", command=onClick1).pack()
 button2 = Button(root, text="Press to Subtract", command=onClick2).pack()
 button3 = Button(root, text="Press to Continue", command=count).pack()

 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Im a newbie in using python so i dont have any idea what is going on.

Comment: Please check the formatting from `def count();` to the end and make sure I corrected it properly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line:

```
for x in range(0, counter):
```

it should be

```
for x in range(0, counter.get()):
```

like it is in your `onClick` functions.